# Check JSON data has specific type then appendTo jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

I have some JSON data that I'm parsing from an Excel file. The one thing I'm trying to figure out is if the First Name in the JSON data equals the name in the data of First Name, then append those data elements to a specific div. The other thing is that if the JSON data  has a 'status', then append an HTML element to that specific element to match. For example:

**JSON:**

```
0: Object { "First Name": "Dave", "Last Name": "Jones", "Title": "Cool Dude"}
​
1: Object { "First Name": "Dave", "Last Name": "Simpson", "Title": "Other Dude", "Status": "Owner"}
​
2: Object { "First Name": "Mike", "Last Name": "Jones", "Title": "The Guy", "Status": "Owner"}
​
3: Object { "First Name": "Mike", "Last Name": "Hampton", "Title": "Worker", "Status": "Employee"} 
​
4: Object { "First Name": "Dave", "Last Name": "Reilly", "Title": "Person"}
```

**JS:**

```
$.each(jData, function (i, f) {
    var name = f["First Name"];
    var status = f["Status"];
    var el =
        "<div class='item'><p>" +
        f["First Name"] +
        "</p></div>";
    if (name == "Dave") {
        $(el).appendTo("#nameDave");
    }
    if (name == "Mike") {
        $(el).appendTo("#nameMike");
    }
    if (status == "Owner" || status == "Employee") {
    $("<small>*</small>").appendTo(".item p");
}
  });
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="nameDave"></div>

<div id="nameMike"></div>
```

Overall I can get the data to append into the ID's of the HTML fine based off of the `name`, but the hangup is getting the asterisk to append to the ones that have the `status`. The way that I have the JS now, it's appending the `<small>*</small>` to each item which is not correct. I'm not sure how to check if the `status` exists for each object and if it does, just append to that specific element. Essentially:

**OUTPUT:**

```
<div id="nameDave">
   <div class='item'><p>Dave</p></div>
   <div class='item'><p>Dave<small>*</small></p></div>
   <div class='item'><p>Dave</p></div>
</div>

<div id="nameMike">
   <div class='item'><p>Mike<small>*</small></p></div>
   <div class='item'><p>Mike<small>*</small></p></div>
</div>
```

Is what I am trying to achieve, but that's not the case currently.

Comment: why are you trying to apply that after creating and writing the element? Seems easier to just add the * directly in the string that creates the P element

Comment: @Kinglish - I was thinking about that but I'm not sure how to check the data to see if the `status` is present in the JSON data. Unless create two separate variables and then append if `status` is present and correct? I guess that's the other part to my questions as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here `$("<small>*</small>").appendTo(".item p");` in this case you append to all `item p` not the specific one .. So you need to add the status HTML to the `el` first before you append it

```
$.each(jData, function (i, f) {
    var name = f["First Name"];
    var status = f["Status"] ? f["Status"] : "";
    var status_HTML = status == "Owner" || status == "Employee" ? "<small>*</small>" : "";
    var el =
        "<div class='item'><p>" +
        f["First Name"] + status_HTML +
        "</p></div>";
    if (name == "Dave") {
        $(el).appendTo("#nameDave");
    }
    if (name == "Mike") {
        $(el).appendTo("#nameMike");
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok great! Yeah, this makes sense. I was starting down this path, but I wasn't sure how to structure the ternary operator.

Comment: You're totally welcome @ultraloveninja .. Have a great day :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
        let jData = [
            { "First Name": "Dave", "Last Name": "Jones", "Title": "Cool Dude" },
            { "First Name": "Dave", "Last Name": "Simpson", "Title": "Other Dude", "Status": "Owner" },
            { "First Name": "Mike", "Last Name": "Jones", "Title": "The Guy", "Status": "Owner" },
            { "First Name": "Mike", "Last Name": "Hampton", "Title": "Worker", "Status": "Employee" },
            { "First Name": "Dave", "Last Name": "Reilly", "Title": "Person" },
        ];

        $.each(jData, function (i, f) {
            var name = f["First Name"];
            var status = f["Status"];
            var el = "<div class='item'><p>" + f["First Name"];
            if (status == "Owner" || status == "Employee") {
                el += "<small>*</small>";
            }
            el += "</p></div>";


            if (name == "Dave") {
                $(el).appendTo("#nameDave");
            }
            if (name == "Mike") {
                $(el).appendTo("#nameMike");
            }

        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nameDave"></div>
    <div id="nameMike"></div>
```